# Count by number of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structure of **TableA** like :

```
-------------------
Id      |   Type
-------------------
12345   |   RegA
12345   |   RegB
23456   |   RegB
45678   |   RegB
45678   |   RegA
-------------------
```

I want to obtain how many *IDs* are having how many *Types* each. In the above case, 1 *ID* is having 1 distinct *Type*, whereas 2 *IDs* are having 2 distinct *Types* each. Hence, the output should be like below:

```
---------------------------
Id_Count    |   Type_Count
---------------------------
2           |   2
1           |   1
---------------------------
```

I'm able to receive the count by individual *IDs* like the below. But not able to retrieve like the above mentioned.

```
-------------------------------
Id_Count        |   Type_Count
-------------------------------
12345           |   2
45678           |   2
23456           |   1
-------------------------------
```

Comment: 12345 has a count of 2 ids and 2 unique types.  why does 45678  not have any unique types in the output

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a second aggregation on your first result (*in the subquery*) eg

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(1) as Id_Count,
    Type_Count
FROM (
    SELECT
        Id,
        COUNT(1) as Type_Count
    FROM 
        TableA
    GROUP BY
        Id
) t
GROUP BY Type_Count
```

**Edit 1:** As highlighted by @mathguy in the comments, if there are duplicate entries in your real dataset the following modification using `COUNT(DISTINCT type)` will count each occurrence of `type` only once in each group and similarly for `id` in `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` may be more suitable

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT Id) as Id_Count,
    Type_Count
FROM (
    SELECT
        Id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT Type) as Type_Count
    FROM 
        TableA
    GROUP BY
        Id
) t
GROUP BY Type_Count
```

Comment: The OP mentions "distinct" type, even though the sample data doesn't have duplicates. It's possible, depending on the real-life data, that the inner query requires `count(distinct type)` instead of `count(1)`.

Comment: @mathguy good observation, i'll update with a comment

Answer (score 0):

you could use count(dictinct type) as result for an outer count

```
 select count(*), type_count
 from (
 select id , count(distinct   Type) type_count
 from my_table  
 group by id ) t
 group by type_count
```

Comment: Did you see the OP's desired output? Your query will generate the output he already has (but does not want). Giving you time to delete the answer or to amend it, before downvoting as "not helpful".

Comment: @mathguy  thank i have see the OP  desired output is over the actula output ..  answer updated..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    SELECT 
      Id AS Id_Count, 
      COUNT(*) as Type_Count 
    FROM 
      my_table
    GROUP BY 
      type 
    ORDER BY 
      Type_Count ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of using a `window function`

```
select distinct 
       count(id) over (partition by count(distinct type)) as id_count, 
       count(distinct type) as type_count
from t
group by id;
```